# Exceptions - Differentiating Exceptions when method raises more than one

Tags: c#, exception, error-code

I got this class which raises same type of exception, how do i capture this exception and display appropriate error message. Here is what i do now.

```
public bool ChangePassword(oldPassword,newPassword)
{

  if(oldPassword != savedInDatabase)
{
  throw new ArgumentException("Your old password is not same as one saved in our database")
}

  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldPassword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword))
{
 throw new ArgumentException("Your old or new password is empty of null");
}

}
```

and i do the below,

```
try
{
}
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
 if(ex.Message.contains("Your old or"))
{
  messagebox.show("Either your old or new password is empty or null")
}
...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just display the message from the original exception? Searching for strings like that is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Oded well i could, but then how do i identify other exceptions of type `ArgumentNullException`. I think better idea is to use friendly message for exception and just display them.

Comment: @PeetBrits `Why don't you just display the message from the original exception` that's exactly how i am thinking now. Just use friendly message rather than checking strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not really justify custom exceptions. I say just display the original message.

However, if you really want to go down the path of custom exceptions, then another option is to create a single custom exception that takes an `enum` with all the different options, like such:

```
public class PasswordException : Exception
{
    public PasswordException(PasswordResult result) : base() { }
    public PasswordException(PasswordResult result, string message) : base(message) { }
    public PasswordException(PasswordResult result, string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
}

public enum PasswordResult
{
    Success = 0,
    PasswordMismatch,
    PasswordEmpty,
    // and so forth
}
```

Comment: Or have the method return that enum.

Comment: @Hans, yes, even butter, but that depends on his situation (e.g. is he using a service where he might ignore the returned value?)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider throwing different exception types. If you wished to stick with the library exception types an `ArgumentNullException` would be appropriate if the old or new password is null or empty. Alternatively you may consider defining your own exception types with a more specific error (perhaps similar to FaultExceptions in WCF), or including a resource identifier in your custom exception (to ensure I18N compatible):

```
public class ResourceableException : Exception
{
  public string ResourceKey { get;set; }
}
```

Then used like so:

```
try { ... }
catch (ResourceableException e)
{
  messagebox.Show(ResourceManager.GetResource(e.ResourceKey));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit over kill for things like argument exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom exceptions like this:

```
public class PasswordEmptyOrNullException : Exception
{
    public PasswordEmptyOrNullException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {

    }
}

public class OldPasswordNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public OldPasswordNotFoundException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {

    }
}
```

They can then be used like this:

```
throw new PasswordEmptyOrNullException("A message");
```

Then you can handle them in a try catch statement like this:

```
try
{
}
catch (PasswordEmptyOrNullException ex)
{
    // Do stuff
}
catch (OldPasswordNotFoundException ex)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

So you can handle different types of exceptions in different ways. Hope that's what you were looking for.